# Split Table into Windows with Recurring Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

My title is awful, because I am not sure how to describe the challenge. I would love an edit if someone can think of a more descriptive title. Hopefully my input/desired output will help explain. Here is some sample input data:

```
create table #input (
    num varchar(10),
    code varchar(10),
    event_date date
)

insert into #input (num, code, event_date)
values('123456', 'Active', '2007-09-10'),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-15'),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-24'),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2018-09-17'),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2019-01-01'),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2019-02-08')

select *
from #input
order by event_date
```

I want to tag each record for each group of num + code with the same number. However, I want the time periods to stay separate. Here is the desired result:

```
create table #result (
    num varchar(10),
    code varchar(10),
    event_date date,
    tag int
)

insert into #result (num, code, event_date, tag)
values('123456', 'Active', '2007-09-10', 1),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-15', 1),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-24', 1),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2018-09-17', 2),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2019-01-01', 2),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2019-02-08', 3)

select *
from #result
order by event_date
```

Obviously normal window partitions like this...

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by num, code order by event_date) rn
from #input
order by event_date
```

...don't work, because there is no field on which to partition that would split the two "Active" groups (two groups, because they happen during two time frames). How would I reach my desired result? I have a hunch that a series of `lag()` and `lead()` functions might work, but I couldn't get anywhere meaningful.

Alternatively, how would I achieve the results so the categories overlap by one?

```
create table #result_new (
    num varchar(10),
    code varchar(10),
    event_date date,
    tag int
)

insert into #result (num, code, event_date, tag)
values('123456', 'Active', '2007-09-10', 1),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-15', 1),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2010-09-24', 1),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2018-09-17', 1),
      ('123456', 'Inactive', '2019-01-01', 2),
      ('123456', 'Active', '2019-02-08', 2)

select *
from #result_new
order by event_date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LAG` gets your half way there, but not the whole way. You can use `LAG` to check the value of the last row, and create (what I have called) a switch. You can then use a `SUM` window function, with a `ROWs BETWEEN` clause to get the value for `tag`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
      SELECT num,
             code,
             event_date,
             CASE WHEN code = LAG(code) OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY event_date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Switch
      FROM #input)
SELECT num,
       code,
       event_date,
       SUM(Switch) OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY event_date
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS tag
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Can you please explain what `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` adds? Removing that seems to give the same result.

Comment: When using an `ORDER BY` in an `OVER` clause, that is actually the default scope @OverflowingTheGlass. I prefer to define it, *just in case* one day it isn't.

Comment: makes sense - thank you. any idea how to make the groupings inclusive of the next record? for instance, in this case, there would only be two groupings: `1` would cover the first four rows, `2` would cover the last two. So when `code` switches, that record where it switches should be included in the previous grouping.

Comment: Not sure I understand @OverflowingTheGlass. The query above returns the result set from your table `#result` in your question; is that not correct? If not, then you need to amend your question to be reflective of the results you're after.

Comment: nope - you were spot on. I am moving the goalposts a bit - happy to post a new question if it's too much off the original. I edited my question with alternative results, just in case